# visual basic 2008 32bit/64bit?

Tags: .net, vb.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

can vb.net 2008 bet set to only run in 32bit?

Answer (score 6):

In Visual studio, In any project right click and select Project properties - > Compile -> Advanced compile options and select the Target CPU for x86, x64 or Titanium

Comment: not all version of visual studio has this option, Visual Studio 2008 in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this setting in Visual studio.

At the **debug toolbar** in VS2008 you will find a dropdown list says “**Any CPU**”.  Select “Configuration Manager”, and change the platform to **x86** or **x64**.   If you don’t see x86, select new… and choose x86.

Comment: I don't see that in my debug toolbar.